# Enable and disable plugins in sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-compiling

How do I enable or disable a plugin in `build.sbt` file in my sbt-cross-platforms project , for example  I want to run the jvm only and disable the native and js.
Any suggestions to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the scala-sbt documentation [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Using-Plugins.html):

You can enable a plugin like this:

```
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .enablePlugins(FooPlugin, BarPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "hello-util"
  )
```

And disable a plugin like thiS:

```
lazy val util = (project in file("util"))
  .enablePlugins(FooPlugin, BarPlugin)
  .disablePlugins(plugins.IvyPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "hello-util"
  )
```

You can simply run the following command in the sbt console to get the information about which auto plugins are enabled for a given project:

```
plugins
```

*One documentation a day, keeps stackoverflow away.*

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Updated link to sbt plugins doc https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Plugins.html